# Filter Gallery based on text in label

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas

I'm struggling with this for days now.

I've made a PowerApp in which a Document Library is shown from SharePoint in a Gallery. In this list there's a label which contains the data from a multiple selection in SharePoint.

[SharePoint Multiple selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWM9W.png)

The values are shown in a label using the formula below:

```
Concat(ThisItem.'Behandelende Afdeling';Value & ", ")
```

This works fine, as you're able to see in this capture: [List in PowerApps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwryV.png)

In this case, 'Klantenteam Groen' is returned.

Now, I want to filter the Gallery in order to show just the items which contain "Inkoop" in the label. So, for example, if the label is "Klantenteam Groen, Inkoop, Order Afgerond" it should be shown in the list, but if it doesn't contain the "Inkoop" part is should not be shown.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

Kelsey.

*The names:*

*- Label which returns the multiple values: Txt_BehandelendeAfd*

*- Name of the gallery: BrowseGallery1*

*- Name of the SharePoint Document Library: Orderproces*

*- Name of the Multiple Selection option: 'Behandelende Afdeling'*

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the current formula on the items property of your Gallery?
The changes should be made on this formula.

If it hasn't been modified, I believe you should have something like

`SortByColumns(Filter(Orderproces, StartsWith(Title, TextSearchBox1.Text)), "Title", If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))`

You can modify it to something like

`SortByColumns(Filter(Orderproces, StartsWith(Title, TextSearchBox1.Text) || TextSearchBox1.Text in 'Behandelende Afdeling'), "Title", If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))`